# Extract KeyValuePair<string, string> from dictionary to another dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm new to a programming with c#. How to extract IEnumarable key value pair from dictionary that has type <string, IEnumarable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> to another dictionary<string, string>? Preferebly using linq. Thank you in advance.

Obviously KvpValues dictionary has some values in it. It's just a pseudo code for present what i have.
Trying to do something like that:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumarable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> KvpValues = new Dictionary<string, IEnumarable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
Dictionary<string,string> values = KvpValues.Values.ForEach(k=>k.Key, v=>v.Value);
```

Comment: What happens in the case of duplicate keys?

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> values = KvpValues.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("A")).ToDictionary(x => x);

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is flatten the `Values` from the original `Dictionary` into a new `Dictionary`. Assuming there will be no key conflicts, your code is close, you just need to convert your `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>>` into a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` which is what `Enumerable.SelectMany` does for you:

```
Dictionary<string,string> values = KvpValues.Values.SelectMany(kvs => kvs).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```